# What is the @ symbol used for in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I've seen this symbol - @ everywhere, especially in java and php and none of my books ever explained what it's used for. I'm learning objective-c right now and the code says

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

I've tried googling what @ is but no search results came up. Can anyone tell me what it's used for?

Comment: *sidenote:* in PHP , `@` before a function is to suppress the warning.

Comment: @ "identifys" an unicode string in C# so you don't have to escape it